# Magento 2 on Mgt Development Environment Nginx conf not rewriting static urls to remove version string

Tags: magento, nginx, magento2

I have been experimenting with the [Mgt Development Environment](https://www.mgt-commerce.com/cms/mgt-development-environment) and it seems to work well but with a fresh install of Magento 2 (latest version 2.1.5) and the demo data installed, requirejs-config.js and jquery-storageapi.js are failing to load (404). The reason for the 404 is that the version string isn't being written out of the URL.

The Mgt Development Environment provides its own nginx vhost conf which is not the same as the conf sample that comes with Magento 2 so I am guessing this is the cause of the issue.

This is the conf:

```
server {
listen 80;
{{ssl_listener}}
server_name eggshop.local;
{{ssl_certificate}}
{{ssl_certificate_key}}
ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout  10m;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128:AES256:AES:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
client_max_body_size 50m;
root {{root}};

{{nginx_access_log}}
{{nginx_error_log}}

location ~ (^/(app/)|/\.+) {
  deny all;
}

location ~ (/(/|pkginfo/|var/|report/config.xml)|/\.+) {
  deny all;
}

location /setup/ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /setup/index.php?$args;
}

location /pub/static/ {
  location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|html|xml)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    expires max;
    access_log off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/pub/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /pub/static.php?resource=$2 last;
        rewrite ^/pub/static/(.*)$ /pub/static.php?resource=$1 last;
    }
  }
}

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location ~ \.php$ {
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   try_files $uri =404;
   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
   fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
   fastcgi_send_timeout 3600;
   fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
   fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT 80;
   fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "
     error_log={{php_error_log}};
     memory_limit=768M;
     max_execution_time=360;";
   #fastcgi_param MAGE_MODE "production";
}

gzip                on;
gzip_disable        "msie6";
gzip_vary           on;
gzip_proxied        any;
gzip_comp_level     8;
gzip_buffers        16 8k;
gzip_http_version   1.1;
gzip_types          text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/png image/gif image/jpeg;

location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|zip|swf)$ {
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
  expires max;
  access_log off;
}

if (-f $request_filename) {
  break;
}
```

}

It does seem to have the rewrite portion in there.

I have tried adapting the conf that comes with Magento 2 to replace this but it won't save - says it is not a valid nginx conf.

Can anyone offer any advice as to why their conf is causing issues? All other static assets are loading fine - css and js. It is just those two files mentioned above.

Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please pull the newest version, we have fixed the issue in the NGINX vhost template some weeks ago.

Comment: On the 5.6 version? Which is what I am using. On docker hub it says last push a month ago and I pulled it only 2-3 weeks ago...

Comment: Please try the PHP 7 version.